# JQuery Chosen: Using trigger("liszt:updated") Correctly

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, jquery-chosen

I have an two different selection for city and district. When user change the city selection I update district selection.

There is my code:

```
$("#city").change(function () {
    $.ajax({
        url: '<?php echo SITE_URL; ?>/process/getDistricts?city=' + $(this).val(),
        type: 'get',
        success: function (data) {
            data = JSON.parse(data);
            var districts = $("#district");
            districts.empty();
            districts.append('<option value=""> İlçe Seçiniz </option>');
            for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                districts.append('<option value="' + data[i].ID + '">' + data[i].name + '</option>');
            }
            $("#district").trigger("liszt:updated");

        },
        error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
            console.log(thrownError + "\r\n" + xhr.statusText + "\r\n" + xhr.responseText);
        }
    });
});
```

If I don't add `districts.append('<option value=""> İlçe Seçiniz </option>');` line, first district option select automatically.

And my "search-choice-close" button disappears like this:

[image]

How can I update my liszt selection correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From chosen [documentation](https://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/):

> Note: on single selects, the first element is assumed to be selected
>   by the browser. To take advantage of the default text support, you
>   will need to include a blank option as the first element of your
>   select list.

That means you need to add a blank element to serve as a placeholder for  the default text.

Also, I cant see "search-choice-close" in your code or the image.

Comment: I forget add blank option. Thank you for your answer.